Automating spaceship thruster according to it's movement
I have a model of a spaceship. I'd like to automate the thrusters to go off during an animation, based on the ship's velocity. I.E., the left thruster would fire when the spaceship is traveling right, and vice versa. What approach should I take? At the moment my thruster exhaust is a plane with an emmission material that is animated to flicker with some noise, so I should be able to just animate the visibility of the thruster on and off, and it will look how I want. But, how can I read the ship object's velocity, and turn that into said visibility animation?

You can use a Simulation Zone in a GeometryNodes modifier to compare the current frame position to the previous one, and project the resulting vector onto a reference direction. The sign of the projection can be stored as a Named Attribute to be used in a shader. May I suggest to read this post about computing the velocity (but not only...) of an object : How to measure velocity and acceleration in real time using geometry nodes in Blender? ?
